# How can I get auto-complete to work for an attribute in my XML document?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, xsd

In Eclipse, if I create a new Spring application context XML document when I press Ctrl+Space while inside the "class" attribute, Eclipse will let me browse through Classes that I can use, for example:

..and Eclipse will show java.lang.String, etc.

I've created my own XSD and now I'm making an XML file that references it. My XSD defines a "class" attribute just like the spring-beans.xsd does but I don't get that same type of auto-complete. Any ideas how I can get Eclipse to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you will have to write your own Eclipse plugin in this case. Just try edit Spring context file in Eclipse without Spring IDE installed and you will see that code completion doesn't work anymore